# Spritekit - Shifting between two functions with a timer

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit

I'm making a game where I have two different functions that holds different types of enemies. I want to make a code that shifts between the two every 10 score. So from 0-10 "function 1" is active, and from 10-20 "function 2" is active, and then it changes back again and then back again and so on.

This is my two functions containing enemies:

```
var score = 0

func createPipes() {
    PipesHolder = SKNode()
    PipesHolder.name = "Pipe"


    let pipeLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PipeRight")
    pipeLeft.name = "Pipe"
    pipeLeft.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    pipeLeft.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 0)
    pipeLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: pipeLeft.size)
    pipeLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Pipe
    pipeLeft.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    let pipeRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PipeLeft")
    pipeRight.name = "Pipe"
    pipeRight.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    pipeRight.position = CGPoint(x: -300, y: 0)
    pipeRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: pipeRight.size)
    pipeRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Pipe
    pipeRight.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


    PipesHolder.zPosition = 2
    PipesHolder.xScale = 1.5
    PipesHolder.yScale = 0.8
    PipesHolder.position.x = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 
    -220, secondNum: 220)
    PipesHolder.position.y = self.frame.height + 100

    PipesHolder.addChild(pipeLeft)
    PipesHolder.addChild(pipeRight)

    self.addChild(PipesHolder)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: -destination, duration: 10)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 200, y: 0, duration: 1)

    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -200, y: 0, duration: 1)


    let moveBackAndForth = 
    SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveRight, moveLeft]))


    PipesHolder.run(moveBackAndForth)

    PipesHolder.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: 
    "MovePipes")

}

func spawnPipes() {
    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createPipes()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnPipes")
}

func createRedEnemies() {
    let enemyHolder = SKNode()
    enemyHolder.name = "Holder"

    let enemyLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")
    let enemyMiddle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")
    let enemyRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")

    enemyLeft.name = "Enemy"
    enemyLeft.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    enemyLeft.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0)
    enemyLeft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 
    enemyLeft.size.width - 5, height: enemyLeft.size.height - 5))
    enemyLeft.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    enemyLeft.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    enemyLeft.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


    enemyMiddle.name = "Enemy"
    enemyMiddle.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    enemyMiddle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    enemyMiddle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 
    enemyMiddle.size.width - 5, height: enemyMiddle.size.height - 5))
    enemyMiddle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    enemyLeft.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    enemyMiddle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


    enemyRight.name = "Enemy"
    enemyRight.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    enemyRight.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: 0)
    enemyRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 
    enemyRight.size.width - 5, height: enemyRight.size.height - 5))
    enemyRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy
    enemyLeft.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    enemyRight.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


    enemyHolder.zPosition = 2

    enemyHolder.position.y = self.frame.height + 100
    enemyHolder.position.x = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 
    -100, secondNum: 100)

    enemyHolder.addChild(enemyLeft)
    enemyHolder.addChild(enemyMiddle)
    enemyHolder.addChild(enemyRight)

    self.addChild(enemyHolder)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 4
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: -destination, duration: 9)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    enemyHolder.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: 
    "MoveEnemies")

}

func spawnEnemies() {
    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createRedEnemies()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.4)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnEnemies")

}
```

Here is the code I have for the shifted functions that I add in the "didMove":

```
func shiftEnemies() {

    if score >= 0 && score <= 10 {
        spawnEnemies()
    } else if score >= 11 && score <= 20 {
        spawnPipes()
    } else if score >= 21 && score <= 30 {
        spawnEnemies()
    } else if score >= 31 && score <= 40 {
        spawnPipes()
    }

}
```

Two problems with the "shiftedEnemies()". The first one is obvious, I cant write a code for every 10 score. The second problem is that this code doesn't even work. "SpawnEnemies()" is the only function that is shown. "spawnPipes()" doesn't show, ever. Maybe problem number two will be solved when I fix problem number 1.

Thx guys!

Answer (score 1):

the reason your `SpawnEnemies` function is the only function that is being called is because you put the function `shiftEnemies` in the `didMove(toView:)` method and `didMove(toView:)` only gets called one time when you present your scene

what i recommend is try calling the function `shiftEnemies()` in the part of code where the score is being added (most likely in your didBeginContact method)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @E. Huckabee! I'm using a counter for the added score that I've put in the "didMove" function. "counter = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: "incrementScore", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)"

Comment: then in the function "incrementScore" add the "shiftEnemies" function so that the function gets called every time a score is added

Answer (score 1):

So you want to start by calling `spawnenemies` and when the score goes past a multiple of 10, switch to calling `spawnPipes` and then back to `spawnEnemies` at the next multiple of 10 etc?

Simply have a bool called shouldSpawnEnemies:

```
var shouldSpawnEnemies = true  // Start by spawning enemies
```

(if you want to start by spawning pipes, initialise this to `false`).

Initialise the score at which functions should switch:

```
var switchFunctionScore = 10
```

Put a property watcher on your score. When the score passes the 'switch' score, set the bool indicating which function to use to `false`. Then set the next score at which functions should be switched.

```
var score : int = 0 {
   didSet {
      if (score >= switchFunctionScore) && oldValue < switchFunctionScore) {
         shouldSpawnEnemies = !shouldSpawnEnemies
         switchFunctionScore += 10
      }
   }
```

Then, whenever you need to call one of these functions; just check the value of `shouldSpawnEnemies`:

```
if shouldSpawnenemies {
   spawnEnemies
} else {
   spawnPipes
}
```

Comment: This works great, but I would mention the issues with using Timer in a SpriteKit game

Comment: Yep - didn't see that. Flinigan - don't use timers - use an SKAction to call your function at the specified interval instead. Sprite-Kit isn't aware of timers and they can mess up the game loop.

Comment: This solution would work with a timer,  just need to make a note to go the hard route of pausing timers and removing them from the loop when events occur

Comment: It would be more readable to make `shouldSpawnEnemies` into an enum, with values of 'enemies' or 'pipes'. Then change the variable name to 'itemToSpawn' or similar. The bool works, it's just less readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using Timer,  Timer works outside of the SpriteKit time system, so for me to cheat in your game,  I could constantly exit and return the app, and since Timer is based on real time and not game time, the time that is spent outside of the game will still be accounted for.

What you want to do is use `SKAction` `wait(duration:)`, 'sequence`, 'run(_ block:)` `repeatForever` and `repeat(_:count)`

To do this, you need to break it down into steps:

1st, we want to wait 1 second and fire function 1:

```
let wait1Sec = SKAction.wait(duration:1)
let function1 = SKAction.run({[weak self] in self?.function1()})
let seq1 = SKAction.sequence([wait1Sec,function1])
```

2nd, we want to create an action that repeats it 10 times:

```
let repeat1 = SKAction.repeat(seq1,count:10)
```

3rd, we want to do this again for function 2:

```
let function2 = SKAction.run({[weak self] in self?.function2()})
let seq2 = SKAction.sequence([wait1Sec,function2])
let repeat2 = SKAction.repeat(seq2,count:10)
```

Finally, we want to combine the 2 and run it indefinetely

```
let seqForever = SKAction.sequence([repeat1,repeat2])
let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(seqForever)
```

Now that we have the action, we can attach it to the scene once

```
scene.run(repeatForever,withKey:"forever")
```

You now have a solution that will constantly fire a method 10 times in 10 seconds, then switch to the other function for 10 more times in 10 seconds, repeating forever.

```
override func didMove(to view:SKView)
{
    let wait1Sec = SKAction.wait(duration:1)
    let function1 = SKAction.run({[weak self] in self?.function1()})
    let seq1 = SKAction.sequence([wait1Sec,function1])
    let repeat1 = SKAction.repeat(seq1,count:10)

    let function2 = SKAction.run({[weak self] in self?.function2()})
    let seq2 = SKAction.sequence([wait1Sec,function2])
    let repeat2 = SKAction.repeat(seq2,count:10)

    let seqForever = SKAction.sequence([repeat1,repeat2])
    let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(seqForever)
    scene.run(repeatForever,withKey:"forever")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Knight! I tried adding that in the code. Not sure if I put it in correctly though. I put all of the code in the "shiftEnemies()", but the outcome is quite different. It starts with on of the functions, and then It just poors on with both functions and also multiplies, at least, all SKSpriteNodes in the function.

Comment: you should only call it once

Comment: yes I did call it once. I meant what happened when I started the game.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong,  it is a sequence of sequences

Comment: But I should put the code above that u mentioned in the shiftEnemies() function?

Comment: Sure, as long as you only call it once in the did move and nowhere else